# Is there a way to set the initial value for an inline jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When initializing a jQuery UI Datepicker, if you're calling it on an input field, it takes the `value` attribute of the field as the initial date to select.

```
<input type="text" value="2016-05-16" />
```

If you call it on a DIV, though, to make an inline datepicker, I don't see any way to specify it.

```
<div></div>
```

I know I could just set it in JavaScript after the datepicker is initialized, but is there any way to set the initial value *in the HTML*?

Answer (score 0):

With some poking around, I noticed that **jQuery UI gives the `<div>` a `value` attribute** to hold the selected date. That's not exactly valid according to the spec, but whatever.

Presumably, this means you can specify a default date value by giving the `<div>` a `value` attribute, the same as an input. I'll update this answer after I test it.

**Edit:** It seems to ignore the `value` attribute when it's on a `<div>`. So the default date cannot be set this way.